Vivaldi won't load on Xubuntu Noble (24.04)
I downloaded the vivaldi-stable_7.0.3495.14-1_amd64.deb from https://vivaldi.com, then started the FileManager from my whisker menu and pointed at the downloaded file.  It ended with an error saying it could not satisfy a dependency "Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libglib2.0-0 (>=2.39.4)"

When I have synaptic look at libglib, I see three installed packages with version listed as "2.80.0-6ubuntu3.1"; those packages are libglib2.0-0t64, libglib2.0-bin and libglib2.0-data
The obvious question is: how do I get Vivaldi on this machine?

Look like a weird discrepancies issue. Lets just install Vivaldi with the official repository.
On a terminal:
we get the PGP key
wget -qO- https://repo.vivaldi.com/archive/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/vivaldi.gpg

then the Vivaldi repo
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/vivaldi.gpg arch=amd64] https://repo.vivaldi.com/archive/deb/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list

then we update
sudo apt update

then we finaly install Vivaldi
sudo apt install vivaldi-stable

